# AWS cloud watch java SDK returning wrong values

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am trying to build a small tester that prints the CPU Utilization of EC2 instances running in AWS.

```
try {
        AmazonCloudWatchClient cw = initializeCW();
        //cw.setEndpoint("https://monitoring.us-east-1.amazonaws.com");
        GetMetricStatisticsRequest getMetricStatisticsRequest = new      GetMetricStatisticsRequest();
        List<Dimension> dims = new ArrayList<Dimension>();
        Dimension dim = new Dimension();
        dim.setName("instanceId");
        dim.setValue("i-4dd6b9dd");
        dims.add(dim);
        getMetricStatisticsRequest.setNamespace("AWS/EC2");
        getMetricStatisticsRequest.setMetricName("CPUUtilization");

        getMetricStatisticsRequest.setStartTime(new Date(System
                        .currentTimeMillis() - 1000*60*60));//Last hour
        getMetricStatisticsRequest.setEndTime(new Date(System
                        .currentTimeMillis()));
        getMetricStatisticsRequest.setPeriod(60*5);//every 5 minutes
        getMetricStatisticsRequest.getStatistics().add("Sum");
        getMetricStatisticsRequest.getStatistics().add("Maximum");
        getMetricStatisticsRequest.getStatistics().add("Average");
        GetMetricStatisticsResult getMetricStatisticsResponse = cw
                        .getMetricStatistics(getMetricStatisticsRequest);
        System.out.println(getMetricStatisticsResponse);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The result I get has the wrong values.
The API response is:
{Label: CPUUtilization,Datapoints: []}

Which is empty.
The real values and the ones available through the AWS console are around 30%.
[See AWS console output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG1fK.png).

The behavior is the same wether I add or comment out the setEndpoint which makes sense since us-east-1 is the default endpoint.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?